# How to change the extract path for Internet explorer driver selenium

Tags: python, selenium, internet-explorer, selenium-webdriver

How to set the extract path using python

"Specifies the full path to the directory used to extract supporting files used by the server. Defaults to the TEMP directory if not specified."

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/InternetExplorerDriver shows that there is a Command-Line Switches that allow you to change the settings. I have tried a few ways on python but I still cannot change the extract path.

Comment: Show the code also that you have tried

Comment: driver = webdriver.Ie('C:/Python36/Scripts/IEDriverServer.exe', extract_path = "C:/IE temp")

Comment: But i have check the webdriver.py there is no extract path. Is this function only for java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like this is not available in latest python binding. But you can monkey patch it to support the same

```
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.ie.service import Service

orig_command_line_args = Service.command_line_args


def patch_command_line_args(self):
    args = orig_command_line_args(self)
    return args + ["--extract-path=/tmp"]

Service.command_line_args = patch_command_line_args

driver = webdriver.Ie()
```

Comment: Why did they remove it when it is important? So yes I can get it to work already. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: They may have not yet implemented it on python bindings. Most works happens in Java first

Comment: Amazing that no one up-voted this answer.  Thanks Tarun.  Worked for me.